# Using a single RDF triple between OWL classes instead of an OWL someValuesFrom restriction?

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web

We have an OWL ontology that contains properties that are intended to be used solely in OWL someValuesFrom restrictions (we don't have an instance level), such as the following (RDF Turtle Syntax):

```
:isResponsibleFor a owl:ObjectProperty;
                  rdfs:domain :Role;
                  rdfs:range :Task.

:SystemAdministrator rdfs:subClassOf :Role;
                     rdfs:subClassOf
                     [ a owl:Restriction ;
                       owl:onProperty :isResponsibleFor ;
                       owl:someValuesFrom :ServerAdministration].
```

While OWL restrictions may be fine in  Functional-Style Syntax or Protégé, they cause a wide range of problems for our RDF-based toolchain, such as:

- Converting between different formats or loading and saving in RDF-based tools makes the output unreadable or hard to process because of disorganized blanknode statements, this also impacts version control.
- Graph-based visualizations show a large amount of unnecessary nodes that need to filtered out and converted to direct edges.
- Editing is confusing, especially for editors who don't know about this problem.

Due to those problems, we would like to model those statements simply like this:

```
:SystemAdministrator :isResponsibleFor :ServerAdministration.
```

We don't use reasoners, so there are no issues with OWL profiles restricting class expressions, but this is still semantically wrong. Also it may be possible that someone actually adds an instance layer in the future, so we would like to find a compromise. Is it somehow possible to model the semantics of the restriction into the property itself or a derivation of it? This definition can be messy, as it only has to be defined once, while we have several thousand restrictions.

For example, there could be a property :isResponsibleForSome:

```
:isResponsibleForSome a owl:ObjectProperty;
                  rdfs:domain [rdfs:subClassOf :Role];
                  rdfs:range [rdfs:subClassOf :Task].
```

And whenever there is a statement between two classes C and D: "C :isResponsibleForSome D", this should imply that:

```
C rdfs:subClassOf
                 [ a owl:Restriction ;
                   owl:onProperty :isResponsibleFor ;
                   owl:someValuesFrom D].
```

However the blanknodes aren't used correctly here because they refer to a specific subclass and not any one. Is it possible to encode this implication correctly in OWL? If yes, how?

Comment: Perhaps _OWL punning_ could help...